# Получение Текста с поля TextField JavaFx Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx

В моем графическом приложение есть текстовое поле(txtField) и кнопка "Search".
При запуске приложения, открывается приложение и пользователь может в текствое поле вписать информацию,а кнопка Search выводит эту информацию в консоль.
Проблема в том, что метод txtField.getText() не получает текст, который записан от руки в это поле. При проверке программа всегда думает, что поле пустое.

Comment: или пользователь вводит техт не в поле `txtField`, или `txtField.getText()` вызывается не в контексте той формы, которая показывается пользователю

Comment: Покажите код пожалуйста.